# Parse XML and get data of certain tags to CSV Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, csv, elementtree

I'm trying to parse the following XML file and get output to a CSV file like below. I tried elementtree. However, it prints no output.

trial.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<!-- random text -->
<!-- random text -->
<meta>
    <valID>
        <ValueID>age</ValueID>
        <desc>Physical attributes | Age at time of evaluation</desc>
        <group>
            <ord>1</ord>
            <name>0 - &lt;5</name>
            <min>0</min>
            <mininc>TRUE</mininc>
            <max>5</max>
            <maxinc>FALSE</maxinc>
        </group>
        <group>
            <ord>2</ord>
            <name>5 - &lt;10</name>
            <min>5</min>
            <mininc>TRUE</mininc>
            <max>10</max>
            <maxinc>FALSE</maxinc>
        </group>
    </valID>
</meta>
```

Desired output (output.csv)

```
ValueID,name,min,maxinc
age,1,0-<5,0,5
age,5-<10,5,10
```

Code I tried:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
document = ElementTree.parse( 'trial.xml' )
for d in document.findall('meta/valID/ValueID'):
    print d.text
```

Comment: What format are you expecting?

Comment: I need it in a CSV file. @AlG

Comment: So is that "output.csv" in your question your desired output or the errored output of the python code?

Comment: @AlG It's the desired output.

Comment: What is your *actual* output?

Comment: @WayneWerner It just prints nothing.

Comment: your xpath is probably wrong. Try `.//meta/valID/ValueID`.

Comment: @WayneWerner I've tried that too. It still doesn't print anything.

Comment: Start smaller. Can you find a single tag? Also - double check that you don't have namespaces prefixing your tags.